# Change registered phone number and email in Authy

Tags: twilio, authy

I am using Authy to implement Two-Factor Authentication in my application.

Registration went fine and I get a authyId that i saved in my system.

But what happens if user loses phone or wants to change his/her phone number ?

How do i allow the user to change email/phone number ?

Comment: Your users can change their email/phone number directly via the Authy app. It should work out of the box.

Comment: @SergioA, What happens in a 'lost phone' scenario ? What must the user do ?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio and Authy developer evangelist here.

The Authy ID is all you need within your application to keep verifying users. If they need to change their phone number or other contact details they can do so within the Authy app.

If the phone is lost and a user needs to change their phone number Authy has a process in place to verify the user identity and allow a phone number change. For more information, please take a look at the Authy site's information on how to [change a phone number](https://www.authy.com/phones/change/).

Comment: Cool, So i do i let my users know that they have to install Authy app on their new phone if they want to change their reg. phone number on my site? Because right now I am going with Authy OneCode that sends an SMS for transaction verification.(I don't have a mobile app yet)